# Gtest: Access auto variable globally across multiple tests

Tags: c++, global-variables, googletest, auto

I need to set global variable `type` that can be used by multiple tests and ideally by all tests in multiple test files.

Please find my script below because of which I am getting the following error: `error: non-static data member declared 'auto'`.

Ideally I would like to know how I can declare this global variable such that it can be used across multiple `.cpp` files. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

**customerTest.cpp:**

```
namespace {
    class custTest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        custTest() {
            type = new TYPE();
        }
        virtual ~custTest() {
            delete type;
            type = nullptr;
        }
        auto type; //this is the global variable that I would like to use across multiple tests
    };

    TEST_F(custTest, openPort) {
        type->defineMap();
        ...
    }   

}
```

Comment: How should the compiler deduce the type of that class member variable? What about using a template?

Comment: I think the problem is that the compiler doesn't have any way of knowing what type of data should be contained in your class member `type`. If you don't know what type of variable to use, you might want to write a __template__ or if the type is one of a small set of possibilities you might want to use a `std::variant`. But `auto` isn't going to work here, because it's intended for cases where the compiler can deduce the actual type of the object from the context, and you haven't provided any.

Comment: @TimRandall sounds good. Thank you explaining

Comment: @TimRandall : you should post your comment as answer

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. How is `TYPE` to be determined? Edit your question
to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the compiler doesn't have any way of knowing what type of data should be contained in your class member `type`. I'm afraid `auto` isn't going to work here, because it's intended for cases where the compiler can deduce the actual type of the object from the context, and you haven't provided any. (We the readers can look elsewhere in the class and find `type = new TYPE();` and infer something from that, but as far as I know `auto` can only look at the statement initializing its object.)

How to proceed, then? If you don't know what type of variable to use, you might want to write a **template**, or if the type is one of a small set of possibilities, you might want to use a `std::variant`.

As for making it available as a global variable: I don't think you need to do anything special, beyond what you'd normally do for a global: declare it in a header file, define it in a source file, and include the header wherever needed. The usual considerations apply. Think about whether it truly needs to be global. Put it in an appropriate namespace so as not to pollute the global namespace. And so on.

Comment: I understand the issue with auto. Proceeding with that, I have been trying to find how I can create a global variable such that the same variable can be shared among files. I read it somewhere that it can be done by setting variable in AddGlobalTestEnvironment(Environment * env); 
Do you have any information related to this?

Comment: @MonaS That sounds like it should be in a separate question. Feel free to ask another one, although I imagine it has already been asked and answered. In the meanwhile, if you're happy with this answer, please accept it. If not, please ask for improvements or clarifications and I'll do my best.

Comment: I have asked this question above as well. Just because it did not get answered, I clearly restated it here again